# Receive an array of characters using SIM900 module

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-ide, c++, gsm, pointer

I tried to receive an array of characters using SIM900, but I couldn't. I can receive just one character like `'G'`, but I want to receive a string `"abcd"`. When I used `char*` to save the SMS, I failed.

Does anyone know how?

My code:

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
SoftwareSerial SIM900(7, 8);

void setup()
{
    pinMode(3,OUTPUT);
    Serial.begin(19200); // for serial monitor
    SIM900.begin(19200); // for GSM shield
    SIM900power(); // turn on shield
    delay(20000); // give time to log on to network. ` 
    SIM900.print("AT+CMGF=1\r"); // set SMS mode to text
    delay(100);
    SIM900.print("AT+CNMI=2,2,0,0,0\r");
    // blurt out contents of new SMS upon receipt to the GSM shield's serial out
    delay(100);
} 

void SIM900power()
// software equivalent of pressing the GSM shield "power" button24 
{
    digitalWrite(9, HIGH);
    delay(1000);
    digitalWrite(9, LOW);
    delay(7000);
}

void loop()
{
    // Now we simply display any text that the GSM shield sends out on the serial monitor
    if(SIM900.available() >0)
    {
        char *in = SIM900.read();
        if (in =="abcd") digitalWrite(3,HIGH);
        if (in == "00") digitalWrite(3,LOW);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It solved . I used another library that manipulated . And just support sim900
U can get it in this below link and include to your arduino IDE 
[This library written by digispark group](http://digispark.ir/files/GSM.zip)

Comment: How was that  solution?

Comment: Right and stable@Aiapaec

Comment: I meant, Could you post the code of the solution?

Comment: No.The solution codes are in the library in answer . You should download library and include it in your arduino ide @Aiapaec

Answer (score 0):

```
#use this code and then inform me"
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
SoftwareSerial SIM900(7, 8);

void setup()
{
    pinMode(3,OUTPUT);
    Serial.begin(19200); // for serial monitor
    SIM900.begin(19200); // for GSM shield
    SIM900power(); // turn on shield
    delay(20000); // give time to log on to network. ` 
    SIM900.print("AT+CMGF=1\r"); // set SMS mode to text
    SIM900.write(0x22);
    SIM900.write(0x0D);
    SIM900.write(0x0A);
    delay(100);
    SIM900.print("AT+CNMI=2,2,0,0,0\r");
    // blurt out contents of new SMS upon receipt to the GSM shield's serial out
    delay(100);
} 

void SIM900power()
// software equivalent of pressing the GSM shield "power" button24 
{
    digitalWrite(9, HIGH);
    delay(1000);
    digitalWrite(9, LOW);
    delay(7000);
}

void loop()
{
    // Now we simply display any text that the GSM shield sends out on the serial monitor
    if(SIM900.available() >0)
    {
        char *in = SIM900.read();
        if (in =="abcd") digitalWrite(3,HIGH);
        if (in == "00") digitalWrite(3,LOW);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi.  Thank u . But these didn't work. I need to choose memory and save sms in side and open it (to this we have need to  use AT commands)

Comment: An explanation of what you changed would be useful.

Comment: It solved . I used another gsm library and worked.@gre_gor